# Controlling a DC Motor 48v with a 63v power supply

Tags: motor, lipo

I have a 1000w 48v DC motor and some Lipo batteries 15s (one 6s and three 3s). My batteries full-charged has 63v (4.2v * 13s).

If I control the speed of my motor through a PWM (using my arduino), I guess I can set the max duty cycle to never reach a tension higher than 48v.

Is that the best way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: Agreement with above but note that the operating freq of the PWM may incur more losses as you raise it.

Comment: Great. Is it safe for my batteries?

Comment: Depends. What does the datasheet for the batteries say about discharge current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I control the speed of my motor through a PWM (using my arduino), I
>   guess I can set the max duty cycle to never reach a tension higher
>   than 48v.

You can use PWM to reduce the *effective* voltage to 48V, but the motor will still be getting pulses of 63V. If the PWM frequency is high enough then current will be relatively smooth despite the voltage pulsing. This occurs because the inductance of the motor windings prevents the current from changing instantaneously.

However the Arduino's stock PWM frequency is only 480Hz which is much too low. At this frequency the motor current will go up and down with the voltage and peak at a *higher* value than it would on 63VDC, causing the motor to run hotter than normal. Most motors need at least 3kHz to get useful current smoothing, and commercial controllers often run 8kHz or higher.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. If the nominal voltage of my motor is 48v, sending pulses of 63V is not dangerous for it? Specially with a high frequency (>3kHz) ?

Comment: According to this post (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=16612#msg121031) I can adjust the frequency higher than 3kHz if I want. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Just be aware that other timing functions may be affected.

Comment: My last question is about the nominal voltage of my motor (48v). Sending pulses of 63V at 3khZ or higher could be dangerous for my motor right? It can overheat I guess? So the PWM is not the perfect solution to reduce the max tension? I'm a little bit lost :( The purpose is to control the speed of my motor using a PWM (I got it) but not sure how to limit the tension max. 48v.

Comment: If the PWM frequency is high enough to maintain smooth current flow then there is little difference between that and pure DC, The brushes and insulation have to handle slightly higher voltage, and the core will heat up a little more, but the effect is small. The main thing to watch out for is that motor current will be higher than supply current, in inverse proportion to the PWM ratio eg. If at 76% PWM you measure 20A the motor is actually drawing 26A.

Answer (score 6):

You actually have a few issues when driving a DC motor with more than the boilerplate voltage rating.

1. **Max Current:** At no time should you exceed the maximum current rating of the motor. It will overheat and can in fact demagnetize itself. As such you need a current regulation or limiting circuit to keep the applied current sufficiently under the max.
2. **Over-arcing:** When you apply a greater voltage the arcing at the commutator  will be hotter. This will increase the wear on the brushes and commutator and dust production. Motor life will be significantly reduced.
3. **Loss of control issues**: You need to take extraordinary measures to account for various additional failure modes. For example, what happens if the PWM driver gets stuck on the ON position, or if you lose your logic supply or the micro/software goes belly up.
4. **Electrical Safety:** The difference between 48V and 63V does not sound like much, but it can mean the difference between a tingle and death. If you plan on using larger voltages, extra care needs to be taken to insulate it and, if it is user serviceable, I'd advise extra labelling on the motor to indicate a higher voltage is present.
5. **Mechanical Safety:** Driving with a higher voltage will mean higher available torque and speed, especially in a failure condition. You should ensure that such changes are within the limits of whatever the motor is driving and can never cause bodily harm. (Over-torque on a hand-drill comes to mind...)
6. **EMC:** Now you are switching higher voltages, you are also adding more electrical noise, not just in the switching, but also in that darn commutator. More significant snubbing circuitry at the motor is likely required.